# gridview boundfield

Tags: asp.net

How do you access the Boundfield object?

I have OnDataBinding="MyFunction" on the aspx and then in the code behind I have protected void MyFunction(object sender, Gridview e). I can't locate the Boundfield object. I can access the first column throught e.Column[1] but I'm interested in the DataFormatString property and that's a property of the Boundfield object.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you for example want to show the time only(and your 2. column is a Date-Column):

VB.Net

```
DirectCast(Me.GridView1.Columns(1), BoundField).DataFormatString = "{0:t}"
```

C#

```
((BoundField)(this.GridView1.Columns[1])).DataFormatString = "{0:t}";
```

Comment: Because GridView.Columns returns a DataControlField Collection. A DataControlField could be a BoundField but it also could be a TemplateField, because both inherit from DataControlField. You know that it's a BoundField but not the Compiler, therefore you have to cast it.

Comment: Getting error as index must be non-negative, I'm calling this method after binding the data on pageload